# signalling a thread with a variable of a type which should be defined later

Tags: c++, c++14

Hy, I have a class which does some complex computations and a handler-class waiting for the computations to be finished. To identify the currently finished computation at the handler, I want to send the id of the computation through the computation-class.

My MWE:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class complex_comp_t {
public:
    using id_t = std::size_t;
    using signal_queue_t = std::queue<id_t>;
    using lock_t = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;

    void do_computation(id_t param);

    id_t wait_for_computation(void);

private:
    std::mutex _mtx;
    std::condition_variable _cond;
    signal_queue_t _signal_queue;
};

void complex_comp_t::do_computation(id_t param) {
    // do some computation (param is not involved in computation)
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);

    // now finished computation
    lock_t lock(_mtx);
    _signal_queue.push({param});
    _cond.notify_one();
}

complex_comp_t::id_t complex_comp_t::wait_for_computation(void) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(_mtx);
    _cond.wait(lck, [this](void) { return _signal_queue.size() > 0; });
    auto ret = _signal_queue.front();
    _signal_queue.pop();
    return ret;
}

//*********************** HERE ENDS THE GENERIC CODE ************************//

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using id_tt = std::size_t;

class handler_t {
public:
    handler_t(complex_comp_t& obj) : _obj(obj) {}

    void run(void) {
        std::thread thread(&handler_t::thread, *this);
        _id = 123;
        std::cout << "Computation " << _id << " starting" << std::endl;
        _obj.do_computation(_id);
        thread.join();
    }

    void thread(void) {
        auto ret = _obj.wait_for_computation();
        std::cout << "Computation " << ret << " finished" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    complex_comp_t& _obj;
    id_tt _id;
};

int main(void) {
    complex_comp_t obj;
    handler_t handl(obj);
    handl.run();
}
```

This example can be compiled with:

```
g++ -pthread --std=c++14 main.cpp
```

Or look at: http://ideone.com/ZrRXT5

**The first question** is now that I want to change the id_t to something more complex than size_t, but the class complex_comp should be so generic, that it doesn't need to know what special type id_t is.

Therefore I have some Ideas:

1. Handle id_t in complex_comp_t as a void*. I know this is not a really good Idea, because therefore I always need to cast the pointer back and I also bypass the type-checking-feature of c++. See at http://ideone.com/k8Z6UN.
2. Generate a interface for the id_t (which needs also a virtual function), that it will be possible, to use dynamic_cast and therefore don't bypass the type-checking, but get some performance decrease. See at https://ideone.com/fhmoj4
3. Use Templates, but this is not an option, because than I would need to implement all the functions in the headers and because complex_comp_t needs some more functions this would be horrible.

So I am looking for a template-free possibility to hold the complex_comp_t as generic as possible, and as type-safe as possible. For example as simple as a forward declaration of the types.

Currently I would prefer Idea 2.

**The second question** is that I don't know if this is a good design decision, to implement signals this way with the combination of a thread waiting for a condition variable and a signal-queue, to be sure that no signal is lost.

Sorry, that I have posted this 2 questions in one site, but I think that maybe if you change the design decision, the first question would be answered also.

Answer (score 0):

Decouple signal data from signal fact.  The task returns a `future<T>` *and* a signaling mechanism.  The signal goes off when the signal is ready, or about to be.

Now the signal code is uniform, type-wise.  Some code has to live in the header to set up the promise/packaged task, but the signal juggling code can be hidden.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't exactly know what you mean and how this would work. Could you please explain it a bit?